# Paypal API - GetVerifiedStatus - Invalid request

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal API in my PHP application. I use cURL to call remote method *GetVerifiedStatus*, but I'm getting an error 580023 - Invalid Request.

My request:

```
 'requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll&emailAddress=email%40address.com&firstName=John&lastName=Doe&matchCriteria=NAME'
```

Response after converting to JSON:

```
{
        "responseEnvelope.timestamp":"2013-07-25T05:36:26.695-07:00",
        "responseEnvelope.ack":"Failure",
        "responseEnvelope.correlationId":"e540c8c04a5b4",
        "responseEnvelope.build":"6679946",
        "error(0).errorId":"580023",
        "error(0).domain":"PLATFORM",
        "error(0).subdomain":"Application",
        "error(0).severity":"Error",
        "error(0).category":"Application",
        "error(0).message":"Cannot determine PayPal Account status"

}
```

cURL code

```
function hash_call_account($methodName, $nvpStr)
    {
        //declaring of global variables

        $this->API_Endpoint_Adaptive_Account .= "/" . $methodName;

        //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->API_Endpoint_Adaptive_Account);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the HTTP Headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array(
            'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
            'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ' . $this->API_UserName,
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ' .$this->API_Password,
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ' . $this->API_Signature,
            'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ' . $this->API_AppID
        ));

        //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
        //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
        if($this->USE_PROXY)
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->PROXY_HOST. ":" . $this->PROXY_PORT); 

        // RequestEnvelope fields
        $detailLevel    = urlencode("ReturnAll");   // See DetailLevelCode in the WSDL for valid enumerations
        $errorLanguage  = urlencode("en_US");       // This should be the standard RFC 3066 language identification tag, e.g., en_US

        // NVPRequest for submitting to server
        $nvpreq = "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=$errorLanguage&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=$detailLevel";
        $nvpreq .= "&$nvpStr";
        //echo $nvpreq; die;
        //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        //getting response from server
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //converting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
        $nvpResArray=$this->deformatNVP($response);
        $nvpReqArray=$this->deformatNVP($nvpreq);
        $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

        if (curl_errno($ch)) 
        {
            // moving to display page to display curl errors
              $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
              $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);

              //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
        } 
        else 
        {
             //closing the curl
            curl_close($ch);
        }

        return $nvpResArray;
    }
```

Config:

```
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.URL', 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments');
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.AdaptiveAccountURL', 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts');
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.api_username', user);
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.api_password', password);
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.api_signature', signature);
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.business', business);
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.PaymentDetailUrl', 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails');
Configure::write('ParallelPayPalAPI.AppID', AppId);
```

Could be problem with version of API? Is there any problem with NVP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem and contacted paypal technical support and the solution was simply that error 580023 is the normal behavior when the name fails to match the email of the paypal account. This is confusing because there is nothing wrong at all with the request, contrary to what the response message implies. So for your example, if you are having the same issue then you just need to change John Doe to the first name and last name of the user associated with the paypal email you are trying to match against.

Transcript from my convo with paypal MTS:

"The error you are receiving is expected. In order to get a response of verified or unverified, the name you provide must match the email address you provide."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Answer (score -1):

[Paypal Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/)

```
580023  Invalid Request.
```

Error code says it's an invalid request, so it's what your sending that's the issue, can you provide your actual request?

Comment: I provided it in my question:
'requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll&emailAddress=email%40address.com&firstName=John&lastName=Doe&matchCriteria=NAME'

Comment: Code + config are posted