# Paypal GetVerifiedStatus with "User is not allowed to perform this action"

Tags: php, paypal

I using PHP library from http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/ to get verify status of a paypal account. In config, api_username, api_password and api_signature are from Verified and Business. But it response

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 550001
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

    [Ack] => Failure
    [Build] => 7784095
    [CorrelationID] => 9beb77e429506
    [Timestamp] => 2013-09-20T03:02:59.383-07:00
    [AccountStatus] => 
    [CountryCode] => 
    [EmailAddress] => 
    [AccountID] => 
    [BusinessName] => 
    [Salutation] => 
    [FirstName] => 
    [MiddleName] => 
    [LastName] => 
    [Suffix] => 
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USvinhnt.dev@gmail.comNONE
    [XMLResponse] => 2013-09-20T03:02:59.383-07:00Failure9beb77e4295067784095550001PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationUser is not allowed to perform this action
)
```

So, i want to know how that and how can i check verify status of Paypal Account?

**Update**

I post this data

```
$GetVerifiedStatusFields = array(
                            'EmailAddress' => 'vinhnt.dev@gmail.com',
                            'FirstName' => 'Vinh Trung', 
                            'LastName' => 'Nguyen', 
                            'MatchCriteria' => 'NAME'
                            );
```

And then, response here:

```
Array
```

(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 580023
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => Cannot determine PayPal Account status
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

```
    )

[Ack] => Failure
[Build] => 7784095
[CorrelationID] => fd4782eabeda1
[Timestamp] => 2013-09-20T23:53:51.560-07:00
[AccountStatus] => 
[CountryCode] => 
[EmailAddress] => 
[AccountID] => 
[BusinessName] => 
[Salutation] => 
[FirstName] => 
[MiddleName] => 
[LastName] => 
[Suffix] => 
[XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USvinhnt.dev@gmail.comNAMEVinh TrungNguyen
[XMLResponse] => 2013-09-20T23:53:51.560-07:00Failurefd4782eabeda17784095580023PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationCannot determine PayPal Account status
```

)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/), GetVerifiedStatus works only with matchCriteria=NAME and mandatory first/last names.

Comment: But when i use matchCriteria, it say "580023 Invalid Request." I wonder why ?

Comment: Can you post your request data?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24767058/1174295 - 580023 Invalid Request is an expected response when the name does not match that of the account