# Paypal API GetVerifiedStatus return User is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hy,

I would like to use GetVerifiedStatus of Paypal API.

So I have create my application and I have an application ID.

In sandbox, all is ok, the service return the status of my customer.

But when I make a live call I have this error :

"User is not allowed to perform this action"

Do you have a solution?

Thanks!

Request :

```
Array
(
    [emailAddress] => myCustomer@email.com
    [matchCriteria] => NONE
)
```

Response :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2013-10-29T06:47:26.456-07:00
            [ack] => Failure
            [correlationId] => 21820ac9a046c
            [build] => 7784095
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [errorId] => 550001
                    [domain] => PLATFORM
                    [subdomain] => Application
                    [severity] => Error
                    [category] => Application
                    [message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
                )

        )
```

)

([Paypal GetVerifiedStatus with "User is not allowed to perform this action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914223/paypal-getverifiedstatus-with-user-is-not-allowed-to-perform-this-action) : This is not the same problem because he update the error with "Cannot determine PayPal Account status")

Answer (score 5):

In order to perform the GetVerifiedStatus call in a live environment, you need to pass also firstName and lastName in the arguments, and they need to be consistent with those of the PayPal account for the email address you are checking. You also need to set matchCriteria to 'NAME'. So, your request would look like:

```
Array (
    [emailAddress]  => myCustomer@email.com
    [firstName]     => myCustomerFirstName
    [lastName]      => myCustomerLastName
    [matchCriteria] => NAME
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try updating the merchant PayPal account to a business account and verify it.